# sort two columns depending on the most recent data entered

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a problem I have a table that I want to sort by date so that the most recent data is first and another column that is numeric that I also want to sort so that the fields that are empty go below those that are not and if I did it with "order" but when I do that it breaks the descending order of the date is there a way to sort without breaking the order of dates.
thank you for your help

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#servicios').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSider: true,
       "order": [[ 2, 'desc' ],[ 3, 'desc' ]],
      "pageLength": 50,
      "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]]
    });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span><strong>STATE</strong></span>
  <select data-column="1" class="form-control filter-select">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="&#10003;">&#10003;</option>
        <option value="&#9866;">&#9866;</option>
   </select>
<table id="servicios" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td>$ 14.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-05</td>
                <td>S/ 124.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-03</td>
                <td>$ 14.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-02</td>
                <td>S/ 124.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-01</td>
                <td>$ 14.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-01</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-01</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/api/sum().js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see, if I order it by amounts, the order of the dates is broken.
[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the rows containing "Garrett Winters", "Cedric Kelly", and "Airi Satou" should be the 6th, 7th & 8th rows (in whatever order), because the first 5 rows will all have "salary" values? Maybe you can add a table of data to the question showing what you want?

Comment: sorry, I'll update it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may not have understood the question fully, but thank you for the update - here is my approach:

1. Add a new column to the table. This will be invisible to the users. It will contain a `1` if there is a value in the `salary` column. Otherwise it will contain a `0`.
2. Add a new `orderData` option which says that whenever a user sorts on the `Date` column, we will actually sort on the new column in (1) above, and then on the date column.

Here is how (1) and (2) are implemented:

```js
columnDefs: [ 
  { 
    targets: [ 4 ],
    visible: false,  
    render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return row[3] ? 1 : 0;
    }
  },
  {
    targets: [ 2 ],
    orderData: [ 4, 2 ]
  }
]
```

Here is a runnable demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table = $('#servicios').DataTable({
      processing: true,
       "order": [[ 2, 'desc' ],[ 3, 'desc' ]],
      "pageLength": 50,
      "lengthMenu": [[5,10,50,-1], [5,10,50,"All"]],
  
      columnDefs: [ 
        { 
          targets: [ 4 ],
          visible: false,  
          render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return row[3] ? 1 : 0;
          }
        },
        {
          targets: [ 2 ],
          orderData: [ 4, 2 ]
        }
      ]
      
    });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.3/api/sum().js"></script>
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span><strong>STATE</strong></span>
  <select data-column="1" class="form-control filter-select">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="&#10003;">&#10003;</option>
        <option value="&#9866;">&#9866;</option>
   </select>
<table id="servicios" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>salary</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td>$14.00</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-05</td>
                <td>$124.00</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>&#10003;</td>
                <td>2022-09-06</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-03</td>
                <td>$14.00</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-02</td>
                <td>S124.00</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-02</td>
                <td>$14.00</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-01</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>&#9866;</td>
                <td>2022-09-01</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody> 
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, your approach helped me a lot,
and the monetary symbols I have two that are soles local currency of my country and dollars which I give them a space to identify them and with a conditional get their totals of each monetary symbol.

Comment: My apologies, I should not have said those currencies were not formatted correctly. I removed that part of the answer.